# How are files on network mapped drives handled locally by a windows host?

Tags: c, windows, networking, windows-kernel, mapped-drive

This is by no means a "give me the solution" question, but more to gain a higher understanding.  Please feel free to point to references where I can learn more about this, I've tried searching and all I get are how to's for setting up and accessing network drives.

I want to be able to monitor a file on a windows machine, but the file sits on a shared drive hosted locally.  If it is manipulated by another machine, is there a process I can look for that will indicate that the file may be accessed by a resource elsewhere on the network?  I understand that the host machine must be available in order to access the file in the first place, but what processes are called to actually manipulate the file.  Is this below the OS level? I have access to a minifilter driver that I can ask a more experienced developer on the team to help me with if need be.

Comment: Actually, I just thought of something.  I'm going to run procmon and access network mapped files.  This should answer my question, I'll post an update once I'm able to get to that.

Comment: Check the *WNET\** functions family (*mpr*). e.g.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnection2a.

Comment: [`NetFileEnum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/lmshare/nf-lmshare-netfileenum) lists the open files on a server. As currently implemented, it makes a remote procedure call to the `NetrFileEnum` function of the "Server" (i.e. LanmanServer) service. In turn, this is implemented with an `NtFsControlFile` (file-system control) system call to "\Device\SrvAdmin", which is provided by the srvnet.sys file-system driver ("\FileSystem\Srvnet").